# Can't set wallpaper in Xfce Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian

Seems like my fresh installation doesnt want to let me change my desktop default wallpaper to any other photo rather than the Debian choices. I also note that if I want to modifying any file, seems to have the same problem. I already use `chmod`, `chown` and setuid but nothing seems to work.

Could anyone give me a hand here?

```
john@terminator:~$ id -a
uid=1000(john) gid=1000(john)groups=1000(john),27(sudo)

john@terminator:~$ stat /etc/hostname
  File: /etc/hostname
  Size: 11              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fe01h/65025d    Inode: 131132      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-11-15 13:10:45.581987866 +0100
Modify: 2020-11-10 00:48:54.560000000 +0100
Change: 2020-11-10 00:48:54.560000000 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Answer (score 0):

right click on the desktop -> Desktop settings -> Wallpaper -> folder -> other

Navigate to folder where are the storage your wallpaper (etc /home/user/pictures) and then left click on "open". If folder conteins pictures then you see them on place of "wallpaper of my desktop" on desktop settings. Choise one of them and have fun...